# Switch to a text console in Fedora

Tags: linux, xorg, console

I have switched recently to Fedora 22 from Ubuntu Gnome. In Ubuntu gnome, when my Kodi media center used to hang while in full-screen, I used to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to switch to terminal.

Then find the process ID with

> ps aux | grep process_name

and then kill the process and use Ctrl+Alt+F7 to return to gnome. What should I do in fedora to switch to terminal like that? Couldn't find anything in keyboard shortcuts and the defaults I mentioned above aren't working. Also is there any other/better way to end unresponsive full-screen applications?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try `Ctrl+Alt+F2`, or F3 or F4...
Unless it was changed in Fedora 22, graphical server is started on first terminal of Fedora instead of 7th in Ubuntu.

P.S. If that works, use `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to go back to graphical server.

Comment: Yep I tried it while Kodi was in full-screen mode. With Ctrl+Alt+F2, got the terminal and  I was able to switch back to graphical server with Ctrl+Alt+F1. Thanks :) I avoided trying random combinations of keystrokes and hence the question.

Comment: fedora 28 opened the console with Ctrl+Alt+F3 with me