# Error when running `startx` on WSL2: Only console users are allowed to run the X server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, startx

The problem occurs when I try to run the `startx` command from the Windows WSL2 subsystem of Ubuntu. I tried to open the graphical environment of Ubuntu.
I have installed Ubuntu desktop. However, When I try to run the desktop environment, I get the following error message:

```sh
$ startx
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when trying to use Xorg: Only console users are allowed to run the X server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478742/error-when-trying-to-use-xorg-only-console-users-are-allowed-to-run-the-x-serve)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Post the text in question verbatim using proper markdown.